# RestFB: Exception: Unable to convert Facebook response JSON to a list of java.lang.String instances

Tags: json, message

I have desktop application which reads Facebook Messages (unified_message in FQL terms), which left on my Facebook Page by other Users.
The problem is: when User writes message, which include link, Facebook automatically attaches some object to the message. And this attachment causes exception in RestFb Lib. Unfortunately, my Page access token will not help, because you have to be logged in as me in Facebook in order to use it. But scenario is very simple, try to leave message on a Page like “www.wheather.com - cool site”. I’ve tried it with RestFb 1.6.9 and 1.6.11 – the same result for both. 
Sorry for formatting. I couldn't do it in other way :(

**Here is stack for 1.6.11:**

```
com.restfb.exception.FacebookJsonMappingException: Unable to convert Facebook response JSON to a list of java.lang.String instances.  Offending JSON is {"38d79791ef0dac6f0b645a87f4d152d7":{"icon":"https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif","fb_object_type":"","tagged_ids":[],"description":"The Weather Channel and weather.com provide a national and local weather forecast for cities, as well as weather radar, report and hurricane coverage.","name":"National and Local Weather Forecast, Hurricane, Radar and Report","fb_object_id":"","caption":"www.weather.com","properties":[],"media":[],"href":"http://www.weather.com/"}}
    at com.restfb.DefaultJsonMapper.toJavaList(DefaultJsonMapper.java:171)
    at com.restfb.DefaultJsonMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJsonMapper.java:653)
    at com.restfb.DefaultJsonMapper.toJavaObject(DefaultJsonMapper.java:290)
    at com.restfb.DefaultJsonMapper.toJavaList(DefaultJsonMapper.java:181)
    at com.restfb.DefaultJsonMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJsonMapper.java:653)
    at com.restfb.DefaultJsonMapper.toJavaObject(DefaultJsonMapper.java:290)
       at myprogram.MyDefaultFacebokClient.executeMultiquery(MyDefaultFacebokClient.java:62)
Caused by: com.restfb.json.JsonException: JsonObject["data"] not found.
    at com.restfb.json.JsonObject.get(JsonObject.java:525)
    at com.restfb.DefaultJsonMapper.toJavaList(DefaultJsonMapper.java:155)
    ... 17 more
```

**Here is stack for 1.6.9:**

```
com.restfb.exception.FacebookJsonMappingException: Unable to convert Facebook response JSON to a list of java.lang.String instances.  Offending JSON is {"38d79791ef0dac6f0b645a87f4d152d7":{"icon":"https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif","fb_object_type":"","tagged_ids":[],"description":"The Weather Channel and weather.com provide a national and local weather forecast for cities, as well as weather radar, report and hurricane coverage.","name":"National and Local Weather Forecast, Hurricane, Radar and Report","fb_object_id":"","caption":"www.weather.com","properties":[],"media":[],"href":"http://www.weather.com/"}}
    at com.restfb.DefaultJsonMapper.toJavaList(DefaultJsonMapper.java:167)
    at com.restfb.DefaultJsonMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJsonMapper.java:602)
    at com.restfb.DefaultJsonMapper.toJavaObject(DefaultJsonMapper.java:279)
    at com.restfb.DefaultJsonMapper.toJavaList(DefaultJsonMapper.java:177)
    at com.restfb.DefaultJsonMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJsonMapper.java:602)
    at com.restfb.DefaultJsonMapper.toJavaObject(DefaultJsonMapper.java:279)
       at myprogram.MyDefaultFacebokClient.executeMultiquery(MyDefaultFacebokClient.java:62)
    . . .
Caused by: com.restfb.json.JsonException: JsonObject["data"] not found.
    at com.restfb.json.JsonObject.get(JsonObject.java:525)
    at com.restfb.DefaultJsonMapper.toJavaList(DefaultJsonMapper.java:151)
    ... 17 more
```

**Here is FQL request:**

```
{
"users":"SELECT uid,first_name,middle_name,last_name,name,pic_small,pic_big,profile_update_time,timezone,religion,birthday,birthday_date,sex,hometown_location,relationship_status,political,current_location,about_me,notes_count,wall_count,status,locale,profile_url,verified,profile_blurb,username,is_blocked,email,friend_count,languages FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT sender FROM #messages)"
,"msg":"SELECT message_id FROM unified_message WHERE thread_id='t_id.238275946308607' AND timestamp > '1360112817564' AND sender.user_id != '507447822604742' LIMIT 100"
,"messages":"SELECT message_id,thread_id,subject,body,unread,action_id,timestamp,tags,sender,recipients,object_sender,html_body,attachments,shares,share_map FROM unified_message WHERE message_id IN (SELECT message_id FROM #msg) AND timestamp > '1360112817564' AND timestamp <= '1360117314920' LIMIT 100"
}
```

**Here is reply from Facebook Explorer on request above:**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "msg", 
      "fql_result_set": [
        {
          "message_id": "m_mid.1360112949050:d17ca4ed7fc6236a75"
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "name": "messages", 
      "fql_result_set": [
        {
          "message_id": "m_mid.1360112949050:d17ca4ed7fc6236a75", 
          "thread_id": "t_id.238275946308607", 
          "subject": null, 
          "body": "Have a look on http://www.weather.com 1", 
          "unread": true, 
          "action_id": "1360112949128000000", 
          "timestamp": "1360112949058", 
          "tags": [
            "inbox", 
            "source:web"
          ], 
          "sender": {
            "name": "Adam Client", 
            "email": "100004967623158@facebook.com", 
            "user_id": "100004967623158"
          }, 
          "recipients": [
            {
              "name": "MB Aerospace Corp.", 
              "email": "507447822604742@facebook.com", 
              "user_id": "507447822604742"
            }, 
            {
              "name": "Adam Client", 
              "email": "100004967623158@facebook.com", 
              "user_id": "100004967623158"
            }
          ], 
          "object_sender": null, 
          "html_body": "Have a look on http://www.weather.com 1", 
          "attachments": [
          ], 
          "shares": [
            "38d79791ef0dac6f0b645a87f4d152d7"
          ], 
          "share_map": {
            "38d79791ef0dac6f0b645a87f4d152d7": {
              "media": [
              ], 
              "name": "National and Local Weather Forecast, Hurricane, Radar and Report", 
              "href": "http://www.weather.com/", 
              "caption": "www.weather.com", 
              "description": "The Weather Channel and weather.com provide a national and local weather forecast for cities, as well as weather radar, report and hurricane coverage.", 
              "properties": [
              ], 
              "fb_object_type": "", 
              "fb_object_id": "", 
              "icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif", 
              "tagged_ids": [
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "name": "users", 
      "fql_result_set": [
        {
          "uid": 100004967623158, 
          "first_name": "Adam", 
          "middle_name": "", 
          "last_name": "Client", 
          "name": "Adam Client", 
          "pic_small": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/371585_100004967623158_2019810380_t.jpg", 
          "pic_big": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/371585_100004967623158_2019810380_n.jpg", 
          "profile_update_time": 1360108999, 
          "timezone": null, 
          "religion": null, 
          "birthday": null, 
          "birthday_date": null, 
          "sex": "male", 
          "hometown_location": null, 
          "relationship_status": null, 
          "political": null, 
          "current_location": null, 
          "about_me": null, 
          "notes_count": null, 
          "wall_count": null, 
          "status": null, 
          "locale": "en_US", 
          "profile_url": "https://www.facebook.com/adam.client.5", 
          "verified": null, 
          "profile_blurb": null, 
          "username": "adam.client.5", 
          "is_blocked": false, 
          "email": null, 
          "friend_count": 1, 
          "languages": [
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**And the last one.** I use redefined FacebookClient. The source was taken from here, stackoverflow.com. I don’t remember exactly why but it was something like DefaultFacebookClient could not correctly map results from Facebook (attachments to Messages).

```
public class MyDefaultFacebokClient extends DefaultFacebookClient {


@Override public <T> T executeMultiquery (Map<String, String> queries, Class<T> objectType, Parameter... parameters)
{
verifyParameterPresence("objectType", objectType);
for (Parameter parameter : parameters)
if (QUERY_PARAM_NAME.equals(parameter.name))
throw new IllegalArgumentException("You cannot specify the '" + QUERY_PARAM_NAME
+ "' URL parameter yourself - " + "RestFB will populate this for you with "
+ "the queries you passed to this method.");

try {
List<JsonObject> jsonObjects = jsonMapper.toJavaList(makeRequest("fql", false, false, null,
parametersWithAdditionalParameter(Parameter.with("q", queriesToJson(queries)), parameters)), JsonObject.class);

JsonObject normalizedJson = new JsonObject();

for (int i = 0; i < jsonObjects.size(); i++)
{
JsonObject jsonObject = jsonObjects.get(i);

// For empty result sets, Facebook will return an empty object instead of
// an empty list. Hack around that here.
JsonArray resultsArray =
jsonObject.get("fql_result_set") instanceof JsonArray ? jsonObject.getJsonArray("fql_result_set")
: new JsonArray();

normalizedJson.put(jsonObject.getString("name"), resultsArray);
}

return objectType.equals(JsonObject.class) ? (T) normalizedJson : jsonMapper.toJavaObject(normalizedJson.toString(), objectType);

} catch (JsonException e) {
throw new FacebookJsonMappingException("Unable to process fql.multiquery JSON response", e);
}
}
}
```

Any ideas will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of RestFB.  Maybe pull the latest from Github, run "ant dist" to create the 1.6.12 JAR, and try calling the new FacebookClient.executeFqlMultiquery method instead of FacebookClient.executeMultiquery().

The new Graph API FQL endpoint is a little different that the old one and this new executeFqlMultiquery() method should hopefully fix the problem you're seeing.  Let me know if not, or if you're having problems mapping the result type correctly.

Here's a quick example of how you might use the new method, copied from https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/restfb/yjCxSQuiieE:

```
static void test() throws Exception {
  FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient("xxx");

  final String threadsFql =
      "SELECT action_id, archived, can_reply, folder, former_participants, has_attachments, "
          + "is_subscribed, last_visible_add_action_id, name, num_messages, num_unread, object_participants, "
          + "participants, senders, single_recipient, snippet, snippet_sender, snippet_message_has_attachment, "
          + "subject, tags, thread_id, thread_participants, timestamp, unread "
          + "FROM unified_thread WHERE folder='inbox' AND has_attachments='1'";

  final String messagesFql =
      "SELECT message_id, thread_id, subject, body, unread, action_id, timestamp, tags, sender, recipients, "
          + "object_sender, html_body, attachments, attachment_map, shares, share_map "
          + "FROM unified_message WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM #threads) LIMIT 2";

  ComplexMappingResults results = facebookClient.executeFqlMultiquery(new HashMap<String, String>() {
    {
      put("threads", threadsFql);
      put("messages", messagesFql);
    }
  }, ComplexMappingResults.class);

  out.println(results);
}

public static class ComplexMappingResults {
  @Facebook
  private List<Thread> threads;

  @Facebook
  private List<Message> messages;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return ReflectionUtils.toString(this);
  }

  public List<Thread> getThreads() {
    return threads;
  }

  public List<Message> getMessages() {
    return messages;
  }
}
```